# How to click "Go" button on go to finder dialog by applescript?

Tags: applescript

How to click "Go" button on go to finder dialog by applescript?
I have below code: "dialogObj" is the dialog of Go to Finder dialog, but the "click button 1 of searchFor" does not work in here.

```
-- Get the search for pop-up object
set searchFor to first sheet of dialogObj

-- Select all the text in the search field and press delete
key code 0 using command down
key code 51
delay 0.5
--Paste file name
keystroke "v" using {command down}
delay 0.5

-- Click the 'Go' button in the search for pop-up
set textField to value of first text field of first sheet of dialogObj
*click button 1 of searchFor*
delay 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In macOS Sierra the text field has been replaced with a combo box:

Try

```
tell 1st sheet of dialogObj
    set textField to value of combo box 1
    click button "Go"
end
```

By the way: If you select the entire text you don't need to press `Delete`. Any pasted or typed text overwrites the selection.

Comment: It cannot work well as your suggestion, my script can work well in mac os 10.10, it cannot work after i update the os version to 10.12

Comment: OK, it works. Thanks! The text field control change to combo box control in version 10.12

Answer (score 0):

You asked: "How to click "Go" button on go to finder dialog by applescript?"
Did you mean "Go to Folder" dialog, like this:

[image]

If so, then a simple RETURN will "click" the Go button:

```
tell application "System Events"    
  key code 36
end tell
```